# How can I create a workbook for each unique value?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've been trying different things, but I can't get this concept sorking.  I'm trying to modify the code from Ron's link below.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006_3.htm

How can I get this to loop through an array of 5 sheets, instead of just one single sheet?  The 5 sheets that I want to filter on, and save, are all normalized.  So, the headers start in row 3 in all 5 sheets.  I just need to place the filter in cell A3, in the 5 sheets, and pass in all the unique values, then save each as a separate file.

I have 10 sheets in my workbook; I want to get the Macro to loop through 5 specific sheets.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Can you [edit] the code you have into the post?

Comment: We are not going to edit the code for you. If you have tried to edit it and it is not working, put what you have in the original post and explain what is wrong. We will help overcome specific problems but will not do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is activate each worksheet that call Copy_To_Workbooks.

```
Sub LoopWorkSheets()
    Dim MyWorkSheets, SheetName

    MyWorkSheets = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5")

    For Each SheetName In MyWorkSheets
        Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
        Copy_To_Workbooks
    Next        

End Sub
```